# INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMER or INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA);
    //Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);


    //cameraIntent.putExtra(
      //      MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        //            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"))
    //);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 3220);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 3220){
        Log.d("ank", "activity");

    }
    Log.d("ank", "activity1");

}
```

I am not able to get onActivityResult when I use Intent_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA or Intent_Action_Still_Image_Camera

When I use Action_Image_Capture then i am getting onActivityResult called out.

I want to use the above two Intents only because when using Action_Image_Camera video option do not come

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to get onActivityResult when I use Intent_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA or Intent_Action_Still_Image_Camera

Neither [`INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA) nor [`INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA) are documented to return a result. I would expect most apps supporting those `Intent` actions to not return a result.

Comment: Is their any other way to start Intent which opens inbuilt camera app having both still and video options

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria: Sorry, but I do not understand that question.

Comment: Actually I don't want to use Action_Image_Capture because it starts camera application to capture Image only. So any other way out to start camera application where we can capture a video as well and return result

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria: No, sorry. Ask the user whether the user wants to capture a still photo or a video, then launch `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` or `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Ankesh have you got the answer from any other source i am stuck with same issue.